# How to refresh a ViewTable from a separate ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I'm trying to create a swift program with a main `ViewController`, and a secondary VC that controls a pop up that overlays the screen. In this pop up, you can enter in login credentials, which will display in a `tableView` in the main `ViewController`.

So far I'm able to save the entered values in the secondary VC to core data, but I'm not able to `reloadData()` for the `tableView` in the first VC, because it just cant see the `reloadData()` function (must not be a public function? Not really sure, as I'm new to swift).

Could someone help me figure out the best way to go about doing this?

Main ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  var account = [Account]()
  @IBAction func onAddAccount(_ sender: Any) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
      print("RELOADED")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  }

  @IBAction func onBlank() {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return account.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = account[indexPath.row].email
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = account[indexPath.row].password
        return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it because `UITableViewDelegate` is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to swift myself. But I think what you are looking for is a [Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) will tell the main controller that the data has been updated and what it's been updated too. It also seems you might need a datasource? So that you can implement model, view, controller architecture.